# GDPR and embedding Youtube videos

Tags: wordpress, youtube, youtube-api

I am embedding Youtube videos on my website, but this sends the visitor's ip address to the Youtube servers, which is not allowed anymore under GDPR law. At least not without his consent.

Did anyone manage to handle this situation properly?
Can I keep embedding videos if I let the user opt-in for this functionality before loading any videos? If yes, what is a convenient plugin to do this?

Comment: Taking into consideration that the IP is always sent to any web server users visit, you probably just need to let them know, via privacy policy, that 3rd party services may collect some data including the IP.

Comment: Unfortunately no, they have to explicitly opt-in before I can send the ip anywhere. For the same reasons Wordpress gravatars have to be deactivated. The same for Google fonts. It's very very very strict.

Comment: See discussion on [tag:gdpr] tag - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366486/burninate-gdpr

Comment: After all, how do you expect Youtube to work if there should not be a direct connection from your visitor's device to YT?

Comment: I would argue that you aren't sending that data at all. YouTube videos are embedded using iFrames, so the client is directly communicating with YouTube, you're never "passing on" that data.

Comment: You may try GDPR solutions like [cookieyes.com](https://app.cookieyes.com)

Answer (score 0):

A mere IP address might not constitute `personal data` pursuant to the GDPR, depending on how it is handled and what data is transferred with it.

According to article 4, paragraph 1, n. 1, of Regulation EU/679/2016 (GDPR), `personal data` `means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person (‘data subject’)`.

The same paragraph adds that `an identifiable natural person` is

`one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, an identification number, location data, an online identifier or to one or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic, mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person`.

Given the above, the mere IP does not sound to me as a piece of information sufficient to identify an user in most circumstances. Let's say that I'm in a coffe shop, on their WI-FI, and I go to your website where the youtube video is embedded. If the only information sent to Youtube is my IP, there's no way for Google to know who I am. The same applies to all those situations in which a user is on an internet connection with a dynamic IP.

To this regard you may look at whereas n. 30 of the GDPR (it's the part before article 1 of the GDPR), where is is explained that `Natural persons may be associated with online identifiers provided by their devices, applications, tools and protocols, such as internet protocol addresses, cookie identifiers or other identifiers such as radio frequency identification tags. This may leave traces which, in particular when combined with unique identifiers and other information received by the servers, may be used to create profiles of the natural persons and identify them`.

This "whereas" confirms that the IP might be problematic where it is combined with other info that can lead to the identification of a natural person. For example if, with the IP address, is also sent a UUID, or another piece of information that can be used to identify the user.

It could be argued, however, that one could link the person to an IP by getting info about the assigned IPs from the ISP. But then the one to blame for making a natural person `identifiable` would be the ISP, not the one providing mere lists of IPs.

So the only situation in which the mere IP address might be considered `personal data` would be where a `natural person` (i.e. not a corporation, but only an actual individual) has a static IP address, and has made somehow identifiable his/her IP address, for example by publicly declaring from what IP address he/she connects to the internet. Which is quite unlikely.

Al the above, of course, applies only and insofar as the only data collected by an embedded youtube video is the IP address, which I am not so sure about. And also you need to assess whether you are sending Google (Alphabet Inc.) any other piece of information. For example, if you are using Google Analytics, then it's a whole different story.

Since the scenarios and different applicable rules are very complex and vast,  I would strongly suggest that you do a quick check up of how the GDPR might actually work for you by running a self-check at [www.autoprivacy.eu](https://www.autoprivacy.eu/)

Comment: After completing the linked self check one have to pay $20 to see the result.

Comment: Found a better tool to check the real cookies at https://gdpr-service.com/consult. Also a paid service but, the cookie analysis it free and, enough to let you know if you need to do changes on your website.